# Format hex string to MAC string

Tags: python

How can I format a hex string ('003de70fc98a') to a MAC string ('00:3d:e7:0f:c9:8a') using a concise statement?

Comment: I know I have to use the format method of Python but I don't know how. I want a small crisp statement without a for loop etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format , http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [104]: hexstr = '003de70fc98a'

In [105]: ':'.join([hexstr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hexstr), 2)])
Out[105]: '00:3d:e7:0f:c9:8a'
```

or,

```
In [108]: ':'.join(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(hexstr)]*2)))
Out[108]: '00:3d:e7:0f:c9:8a'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regex:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=..)(..)', r':\1', '003de70fc98a')
'00:3d:e7:0f:c9:8a'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = '003de70fc98a'
':'.join(s[i]+s[i+1] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))
=> '00:3d:e7:0f:c9:8a'
```